# How do I determine which set these belong to? Lots of yellow and blue, wheels, some grey

Tags: set-identification

How can I determine which set this is?[image]

Answer (score 4):

[60079-1 Training Jet Transporter](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=60079-1)

Based on

- Yellow Bracket 1 x 2 - 2 x 4
- Blue Plate 6 x 6

[image: 60079]